# Markdown - Link to file in subfolder

Tags: html, server, markdown, jekyll

My markdown "site" is in folder: b-vis
In this file I want to link my JavaDov which is as "index.html" in the subfolder "b-vis/doc-com/index.html"

I tried the following:

```
[This link](/b-vis/doc-com/index.html)
```

But this doesnt work. My server is running local with jekyll. Can someone tell me what the link should be?

Comment: So you're running `jekyll serve` from `site` folder or from `b-vis` folder ? Do you use something else than `baseurl: ""` in your _config.yml file ?

Comment: I am running jekyll serve from b-vis and I just got 'url: http://localhost:4000' in my config.yml file. What should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running `jekyll serve` from `b-vis` folder the correct link from 
`b-vis/index.html` to `/b-vis/doc-com/index.html` is

```
[This link](/doc-com/index.html)
```

Comment: I'd recommend removing the leading forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

try this path:

```
 b-vis/doc-com/index.html
```

instead of:

```
/b-vis/doc-com/index.html
```

(maybe the slash is making your path absolute)